# Grocery Checkout Lines using Queues in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

This is my assignment over queues. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSXLS.png)
I have a rubric of everything I need to make sure I have in order to make a perfect score. I ran into two problems. First problem I ran into was: I'm not too sure how to make customers enter/exit the lines. I know there's some lines of code I need to write but my brain at this point cannot wrap around it. Second problem I ran into was: When I run my program, it shows which customers is joining what queues. However, it's not randomized. They come in a order and I need to make it to where it comes at random time with a random order. I probably can't explain this well so hopefully the assignment description helps and also my output screenshot! here is my output: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfYDS.png). and here is my code so far. What can I do to fix my issue?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numCheckoutLines = 5;
    Queue<Integer>[] checkoutLines = new Queue[numCheckoutLines];
    Random random = new Random();

    // Initialize checkout lines
    for (int i = 0; i < numCheckoutLines; i++) {
        checkoutLines[i] = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    int numCustomers = 10; // Change this value as needed

    // Generate and enqueue customers
    for (int i = 1; i <= numCustomers; i++) {
        int shortestLineIndex = findShortestLine(checkoutLines);
        checkoutLines[shortestLineIndex].offer(i);
        System.out.println("Customer " + i + " joined Queue " + (shortestLineIndex + 1));
    }

    // Simulate checkout process
    for (int time = 1; !allQueuesEmpty(checkoutLines); time++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numCheckoutLines; i++) {
            if (!checkoutLines[i].isEmpty()) {
                int customer = checkoutLines[i].poll();
                System.out.println("Queue " + (i + 1) + ": Customer " + customer + " is checking out.");
                // Simulate checkout time (random time between 1 and 5 seconds)
                int checkoutTime = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
                if (checkoutTime == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Queue " + (i + 1) + ": Customer " + customer + " has an issue and needs assistance.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Find the shortest checkout line
private static int findShortestLine(Queue<Integer>[] checkoutLines) {
    int shortestLineIndex = 0;
    int minLength = checkoutLines[0].size();

    for (int i = 1; i < checkoutLines.length; i++) {
        int length = checkoutLines[i].size();
        if (length < minLength) {
            minLength = length;
            shortestLineIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return shortestLineIndex;
}

// Check if all checkout lines are empty
private static boolean allQueuesEmpty(Queue<Integer>[] checkoutLines) {
    for (Queue<Integer> line : checkoutLines) {
        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of linking to a picture of a problem, or a picture of output, paste the problem and the output. Text is always better in text format, rather than in image format.

Comment: Off-topic: Someone who knows more about Java generics than I do should take a look at this, and possibly talk to your professor, or set me straight. The issue is here: *"You can use an array of queues to simulate checkout lines."*  Java generics and arrays don't mix well. I would expect an array of queues to generate a `generic array creation` error. Instead, try `List <Queue<Integer>> checkoutLines = new ArrayList<> (5);`.

Answer (score 0):

There is some lack of clarity in the instructions your professor gave. The instructions are open to interpretation. It may be the professor relied on students' understanding of material presented in the lecture or previous assignments. However, we on Stack Overflow don't have access to that unless you update the question. It may be the students need to discuss this with the professor and request explanations. Presenting examples would be a good idea.

Nonetheless, I have some suggestions:

**First** *"Each transaction takes a random amount of time to complete."*

I assume a transaction is a customer checking out. One way to handle this is to "glue" transaction time to a customer. Fields can be "glued" together through instances of a `class`. So, a `Customer` class may be appropriate:

```
 public class Customer {
   public static int nextID = 0;
   private final int customerID;
   private int transactionTime;  // remaining, countdown 

   public Customer () { 
       customerID = ++nextID;
       transactionTime = 10;
   }

   public Customer (int time) { 
      customerID = ++nextID;
      transactionTime = time;
   }

   public int getID () { return customerID; }
   public int tick () { return --transactionTime; }  
   @Override
   public String toString () { return "Customer " + customerID + " "; }
}
```

The constructor assigns customer numbers in order. I do not believe having the customer numbers in random order is a requirement.

The transaction time is number of clock ticks to complete a transaction.

**Next**, I would like to mention an issue with arrays and generics. Because of the way generics were implemented in Java, arrays and generics do not work well together. You should not create an array of a generic `Collection`. A line such as the following will generate an "generic array creation" compiler error:

```
Queue<Integer>[] checkoutLines = new Queue<Integer>[numCheckoutLines];
```

To get around that, you can nest generics. In the suggested code in this answer, I used this line:

```
List<Queue<Customer>> checkoutLines = new ArrayList<>(NUM_CHECKOUT_LINES);
```

If you want to access a specific checkout queue, use code like the following:

```
 Queue<Customer> lane = checkoutLines.get(3);
```

This accesses lane 3. Of course, you would replace `3` with a variable or expression that resolves to an integer.

The code for `findShortestLine` and `allQueuesEmpty` looks like this:

```
// Find the shortest checkout lane
private static int findShortestLine(List<Queue<Customer>> checkoutLines) {
    int shortestLineIndex = 0;
    int minLength = checkoutLines.size();

    for (int i = 1; i < checkoutLines.size(); i++) {
        int length = checkoutLines.get(i).size();
        if (length < minLength) {
            minLength = length;
            shortestLineIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return shortestLineIndex;
}

// Check if all checkout lines are empty
private static boolean allQueuesEmpty(List<Queue<Customer>> checkoutLines) {
    for (Queue<Customer> line : checkoutLines) {
        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**By the way**, Named constants are usually declared with `final`, and with names written in all uppercase.  The beginning of the program looks like this:

```
    public class GroceryStore {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

          final int    NUM_CHECKOUT_LINES = 5;
          final double PROBABILITY_CUSTOMER_JOINS = 0.35;
          final int    MAX_TRANSACTION_TIME = 25;
          final int    MAX_CUSTOMERS = 40;    

          List<Queue<Customer>> checkoutLines
               = new ArrayList<>(NUM_CHECKOUT_LINES);
          Random random = new Random();
```

- `NUM_CHECKOUT_LINES` is your `numCheckoutLines`
- `MAX_CUSTOMERS` is the maximum number of customers that will be processed in one run of the simulation. It corresponds to your
- `numCustomers`, but is not quite the same.
- `MAX_TRANSACTION_TIME` is the maximum amount of time (ticks) a customer will take to check out.
- `PROBABILITY_CUSTOMER_JOINS` is the probability that one customer will begin waiting in line in one tick.

**Trivial** Since you are to "Open" the store with one customer in each lane, you can create the lanes and first customers at the same time.

```
    // Initialize checkout lines
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHECKOUT_LINES; i++) {
        checkoutLines.add(new LinkedList<Customer>());
        checkoutLines.get(i).add
            (new Customer(random.nextInt(MAX_TRANSACTION_TIME)));
        System.out.println (checkoutLines.get(i).peek() 
                + "joined queue " +  i);
    }
```

**And now, the main idea:**

The main idea is to run the simulation one-clock-tick-at-a-time until all queues are empty, just as you coded in the main loop. With each tick we want to do two things:

- Add a customer or not, at random. This code generates a random `double` in the range [0.0, 1.0). If the generated number exceeds `PROBABILITY_CUSTOMER_JOINS`, the customer is not added.
- Decrease the remaining transaction time for the first customer in each lane by one tick. If a remaining time reaches zero, the transaction is complete, and the customer leaves the queue.

  ```
        for (int time = 1; !allQueuesEmpty(checkoutLines);  time++) {
           if (     Customer.nextID < MAX_CUSTOMERS 
                 && random.nextDouble() < PROBABILITY_CUSTOMER_JOINS) {
           int shortestLineIndex = findShortestLine(checkoutLines);
           Customer customer = 
              new Customer(random.nextInt(MAX_TRANSACTION_TIME));
           if (checkoutLines.get(shortestLineIndex).offer(customer)) {
               System.out.println("Customer " + customer.getID()
                       + " joined queue " + (shortestLineIndex));
           } else {
               System.out.println (customer 
                    + " got frustrated and left the store " 
                    + "without checking out!");
           }
       }

       for (int lane = 0; lane < checkoutLines.size (); lane++) {
           Customer customer = checkoutLines.get(lane).peek();
              if (customer == null) { continue; } // lane empty
              if (customer.tick() <= 0) { 
                 System.out.println (customer + "is checking out from queue "
                       + lane);
                 checkoutLines.get(lane).remove();
           }
       }                     
   }
  ```

  }

**Other thoughts**

- It is possible the program will terminate before the number of customers generated reaches MAX_CUSTOMERS. If MAX_CUSTOMERS is reached, the program should continue to run until all customers have checked out.
- You might consider having the possibility that more than one customer could get in line during one tick.
- I like that you coded methods to find the shortest line, and tested for all queues empty. You might consider coding a method to add a customer.
- You might want to code a consistent way of accessing a customer. I wanted to show that a customer can be accessed within a Collection by using a (temporary) `Customer` reference, and doing that without.
- Do not assume this code is bug free!
- Demo run:

```
Customer 1 joined queue 0
Customer 2 joined queue 1
Customer 3 joined queue 2
Customer 4 joined queue 3
Customer 5 joined queue 4
Customer 6 joined queue 1
Customer 7 joined queue 2
Customer 8 joined queue 3
Customer 9 joined queue 4
Customer 10 joined queue 1
Customer 11 joined queue 2
Customer 12 joined queue 3
Customer 3 is checking out from queue 2
Customer 13 joined queue 2
Customer 14 joined queue 4
Customer 1 is checking out from queue 0
Customer 4 is checking out from queue 3
Customer 5 is checking out from queue 4
Customer 15 joined queue 3
Customer 2 is checking out from queue 1
Customer 16 joined queue 1
Customer 7 is checking out from queue 2
Customer 17 joined queue 2
Customer 6 is checking out from queue 1
Customer 18 joined queue 1
Customer 8 is checking out from queue 3
Customer 19 joined queue 3
Customer 9 is checking out from queue 4
Customer 20 joined queue 4
Customer 10 is checking out from queue 1
Customer 14 is checking out from queue 4
Customer 16 is checking out from queue 1
Customer 11 is checking out from queue 2
Customer 18 is checking out from queue 1
Customer 20 is checking out from queue 4
Customer 12 is checking out from queue 3
Customer 15 is checking out from queue 3
Customer 19 is checking out from queue 3
Customer 13 is checking out from queue 2
Customer 17 is checking out from queue 2
```